# What is the difference between the onFocus and onMouseEnter event?

Tags: javascript, dom

What is the difference between the onFocus and onMouseEnter event?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

onFocus, when applied to form elements, is triggered when the field is given focus by either tabbing to the field or clicking on it so you can enter a value. Most HTML elements are not given focus through onMouseEnter in any case, so the two events are completely different.

Comment: Also, only IE supports the mouseenter event natively. All browsers support the focus event.

Answer (score 2):

The `onfocus` event fires when the user clicks on an element, usually `<input>` or `<textarea>` elements, and the `mousover` event fires when the pointer mouses over any element on the page.  The `mouseenter` event, however, is a non-standard event used by IE and [implemented by some javascript libraries](http://demos.mootools.net/Mouseenter).

Comment: Actually `mouseenter` is native in IE.

Answer (score 1):

You get the onMouseEnter when the mouse just hovers over the object.  You can also get focus with the keyboard by tabbing to the control or programatically.